# Regular procedure followed by the pilots before takeoff?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airline-operations, takeoff, pilots, aircraft-manufacturer

What are the list of procedures (checks) followed by A320 and A380? Are these procedures decided by the airlines and (or) the manufacturer, or by the Civil Aviation Regulatory Authority of the respective country?

Comment: The checklists are prepared by the manufacturers and the airlines. But the details will be very different depending on the type of aircraft so it isn't really possible to give a single checklist, unless it's a very generic one. Can you explain a bit more about exactly what information you need?

Comment: Which checklist are you asking about? E.g. the before takeoff checklist? It will differ between different aircraft models, so specifying only the A320 or only the A380 will also help.

Comment: I've already editted the question specifically for A320 and A380, why the "On Hold" then?

Comment: Because it's still incredibly broad.  Every airline will have it's own check lists for aircraft operation, and those checklists (when compiled together) usually are hundreds of pages long.  You'd be better off asking for a specific checklist, for a specific operation for a single airliner...

Comment: Though, you also might consider taking that second question (about who makes the checklists) and making it it's own question.  It's a great question, I'd like to see the answer myself.

Comment: @JayCarr Done..! http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15671/who-decides-the-regular-procedure-followed-by-the-pilots-before-takeoff

Comment: Nice!  Upvoted it, hoping for an answer :).

Comment: You can find online Flight Crew Training Manuals which contain instructions about what to do at different stages of the flight. Checklists are part of this preparation and verification. [FCTM for A320](http://www.737ng.co.uk/A320%20321%20FCTM%20Flight%20Crew%20Training%20Manual.pdf). [PPRuNe](http://www.pprune.org/tech-log/266936-a320.html) has the answer you may look for.

Comment: This is three completely separate questions, two of which have essentially one answer per airline that operates the plane. That's ridiculously broad.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to search "Before Takeoff Checklist". Manufacturer will provide standard checklist but airlines can modify it.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer